# is it possible to add Hyperlink using Quip API

Tags: api, hyperlink, quip

I am using the quip api to update a spreadsheet embedded in a doc.
I want to know if I can add hyperlinks using the api.

I will have the link in one column the text in another , create a third column which will have the hyperlink text.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is no requirement for an API, a straightforward formula can be used instead.

```
=hyperlink("URL","Label to be shown")
```